# Unduplicated divisors/sum of divisors

Tags: java, math

I have got problem with program that is generating two numbers in range 100-999 for variable **a** and **b**. Random number generator should breaking when number **b** is bigger than **a**. I need to
a) check how many common unduplicated divisors have got this numbers
b) print sum of divisors that are not common as variable **a** and **b**
I already have got code that generating me var **a,b** (with bigger **b**) and i thought that i have got also loop that provide me divisors but seems like not.
What should i change to provide proper type of divisors? Or any of them-because its not working good.

Thank you for answer.

---

```
public class Ex3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int a,b;
        List<Integer> divider= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while(true)
        {
            a = rand.nextInt(900) + 100;
            b = rand.nextInt(900) + 100;
            System.out.println(a + "" + b);
            if(b>a) {

                for(int i=2;i<a;i++){
                    if((a % i)==0) divider.add(i); 
                }
                System.out.println(divider.toString());
                for(int i=2;i<a;i++){
                    if((b % i)==0) divider.add(i);
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want are all the **Common Divisors** which can be divided into each of the randomly generated integer values and leave no remainder. Divisors would normally start from **1** and incrementally (by 1) work their way up to the random value `a` and random value `b`. Of course the common divisors detected are stored and later displayed when the divisor search is done.

The first **for** loop in the example code below does this divisor search. As you look at the loop you can see the difference from your code. You were right with your assumption about *what you should change to provide proper type of divisors*.

So, the example code below:

- Generates two random integer values from 100 (inclusive) to 999
  (inclusive) as per your specifications.
- Ensures that the random integer value in variable **b** is larger
  than the random integer value in variable `a`. A **while** loop is
  used solely for this specific purpose and this purpose alone. The
  loop condition ensures that the value in `b` must be larger than
  the value in `a` in order to exit that loop.
- The Random values are displayed to Console.
- A **for** loop is used against both the value in `a` and the value 
  in `b` to acquire **Common Divisors**. Note how this is done, pay
  special attention to the
  [termination](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)
  (or otherwise known as the Condition) section of the **for** loop
  statement. Also note the
  [initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)
  section of the loop statement, you can see we initialize the integer
  variable `i` to **1**, not 2. Any determined common divisors are stored
  within a List Interface object named `commonDivisors`. A integer variable named `uncommonSum` also keeps a sum of all divisors that are uncommon via a **else** statement within the loop code block.
- The Common Divisors are displayed to the console window. You will
  notice that **1** is always a common divisor. This only makes sense
  since any number divided by one will equal that number with no
  remainder.
- Finally, a **for/each** loop is used to sum the common divisors
  contained within the `commonDivisors` List and the result is placed
  within a Integer variable named `commonDivisorsSum` which is then
  displayed to the Console window.

An example output to the console window might look like this:

```
Random Numbers:   --> A: 848 | B: 976
Common Divisors:  --> [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
Common Div Sum:   --> 31
UnCommon Div Sum: --> 359945
```

> **Here is the example code:**

```
int a = new Random().nextInt(999 - 100 + 1) + 100;
int b = 0;

// Loop until the random number in b is greater than in a.
while (a >= b) {
    b = new Random().nextInt(999 - 100 + 1) + 100;
}
//Display random generated integer values for A and B.
System.out.println("Random Numbers:  --> A: " + a + " | B: " + b);

// Get Common Divisors between the two random integer values...
List<Integer> commonDivisors = new ArrayList<>();
int uncommonSum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= a && i <= b; i++) {
    if(a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) {
        commonDivisors.add(i);
    }
    else {
        uncommonSum += i;
    } 
}
System.out.println("Common Divisors: --> " + commonDivisors);

// Get an display the sum of Common Divisors 
int commonDivisorsSum = 0; 
for (int i : commonDivisors) {
    commonDivisorsSum = commonDivisorsSum + i;
}
System.out.println("Common Div Sum:  --> " + commonDivisorsSum);
System.out.println("UnCommon Div Sum: --> " + uncommonSum);
```

Comment: Seems to be wrong. The problem asks for two sums of divisors that are *not* common and that are *not* duplicated (which, to my mind, means 'ignore the power of prime divisors' - not sure about this one, would worth asking the poster for clarifications)